# project compiling problems in kitkat and jellybean device

Tags: android

Am a beginner in android development. I have created one project its running only on lollipop device but not in lower versions of android while am trying to run in lower versions the app get stopped don't know what is the reason ?

It need my app to be run on all devices.What should i do to solve this issue ? Give me your suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

While running in jellybean device am getting log cat like this:

```
08-13 10:40:47.770  26187-26187/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sentientit.theiWedplanner/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
        at com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage.onCreate(Frontpage.java:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4864)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:686)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
            at com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage.onCreate(Frontpage.java:50)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob" on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner-2.apk
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4864)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:686)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
            at com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage.onCreate(Frontpage.java:50)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

xml file

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/adview153613"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/aagr_background2" >

    <ImageView        
              android:id="@+id/addviewimage"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp"                    
              android:src="@drawable/adview1536132" />        

   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
       xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
       ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-8424377947693833/3688810888"
         />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/addviewimage1"
          android:layout_width="@dimen/fwh"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/fwh"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
          android:src="@drawable/close" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

these are the versions used

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sentientit.theiWedplanner"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 13
        versionName "11.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

source of xml file

```
    public class Fragadmob extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragadmob, container,   false);

        //Admob        
         RelativeLayout gonad=(RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adview153613);
         ImageView addviewimage=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.addviewimage);
         ImageView inap=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.addviewimage1);

         //   AdView adView = new AdView(getActivity());
           AdView adView = (AdView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
          AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
              .build();
          adView.loadAd(adRequest);
         addviewimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent viewIntent =
                          new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                            Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=SentientIT+America,+LLC"));
                          startActivity(viewIntent);                

            }

         });
         inap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Inapp.class);
                     startActivity(intent);         

                }

             });

          if(addviewimage.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
            {            
             addviewimage.getLayoutParams().height = 30;                    
                // code to do for Portrait Mode
            } 
          SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            boolean isPurchase = preferences.getBoolean("isPurchase",false);
  if(isPurchase){

       gonad.setVisibility(View.GONE); //work 
  }
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Comment: when starting the project, for what api did you choose? if you choose a higher api it might not work or have unknown behavior on lower versions of android

Comment: defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sentientit.theiWedplanner"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 13
        versionName "11.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

Comment: The versions am using is mentioned above

Comment: u there @Avishay Cohen

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you use an android component in your Fragadmob fragment layout file in line 10 which is only available in Lollipop.

Comment: what is that component name?how can i change it to be run on all versions

Comment: Best would be to post your layout files here.

Comment: And also the source of your Fragadmob fragment

Comment: Ingo Schwarz did you see the source file??